# distinct on with case when

Tags: sql

I need your help with conditional "distinct on".
For example I have a table "users".

| id | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 17 |
| 2 | Sam | 18 |
| 3 | John | 12 |
| 4 | Sam | 19 |

And I want to do something like:

```
select case when (u.age > 17) then (distinct on u.name u.*) else (u.*) from users u order by u.name
```

And I want to do "distinct on" BUT with exclusion, if age is less than 17, then display them as well, if age is greater then take random one.
The output I want is:

| id | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 17 |
| 2 | Sam | 18 |
| 3 | John | 12 |

There are two users with name Sam, and both have age > 17, then I want to apply distinct on in this case.
But there's at least 1 John with age less than 17, therefore I want to have all users with name John in the output.

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible to put this in a condition, but in my opinion, that leads to bad readability.

I would prefer to use `UNION ALL` here to clearly split these two parts of your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (name) id, name, age 
FROM users
WHERE age > 17
UNION ALL
SELECT id, name, age 
FROM users
WHERE age <= 17
ORDER BY id;
```

And yes, I know this will select twice from the table, but I think this better in this case unless you observe a very poor performance using this query.

Comment: yeah I also was thinking about this option